# Wired network trouble after migration from Arch to Parabola. Status degraded

Tags: networking, dhcp, systemd-networkd

`/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network`

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
```

`networkctl`

```
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP     
  1 lo               loopback           carrier     unmanaged 
  2 eth0             ether              degraded    configuring
  3 wlan0            wlan               off         unmanaged 

3 links listed.
```

`networkctl status eth0`

```
* 2: eth0
       Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
    Network File: /etc/systemd/network/eth0.network
            Type: ether
           State: degraded (configuring)
            Path: platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.1:1.0
          Driver: smsc95xx
          Vendor: Standard Microsystems Corp.
           Model: SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
      HW Address: b8:27:eb:09:05:c7 (Raspberry Pi Foundation)
         Address: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe09:5c7
                  fe80::c110:1100:8995:68f2
```

`systemctl status systemd-networkd`

```
* systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.d
           `-10-debug.conf
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-02-03 06:44:09 CET; 11h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
 Main PID: 746 (systemd-network)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
           `-746 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

Feb 03 17:52:34 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Next retransmission in 1min 50s
Feb 03 17:52:48 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCP CLIENT (0x26937bab): DISCOVER
Feb 03 17:53:52 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCP CLIENT (0x26937bab): DISCOVER
Feb 03 17:54:25 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Sent INFORMATION-REQUEST
Feb 03 17:54:25 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Next retransmission in 1min 52s
Feb 03 17:54:55 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCP CLIENT (0x26937bab): DISCOVER
Feb 03 17:56:00 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCP CLIENT (0x26937bab): DISCOVER
Feb 03 17:56:18 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Sent INFORMATION-REQUEST
Feb 03 17:56:18 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Next retransmission in 2min
Feb 03 17:57:05 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCP CLIENT (0x26937bab): DISCOVER
```

`systemctl status systemd-resolved`

```
* systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-02-03 02:31:17 CET; 15h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/resolved
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
 Main PID: 327 (systemd-resolve)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
           `-327 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-resolved

Feb 03 02:31:17 MyComputer systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
Feb 03 02:31:17 MyComputer systemd-resolved[327]: Positive Trust Anchors:
Feb 03 02:31:17 MyComputer systemd-resolved[327]: . IN DS 19036 8 2 49aac11d7b6f6446702e54a1607371607a1a41855200fd2ce1cdde32f24e8fb5
Feb 03 02:31:17 MyComputer systemd-resolved[327]: Negative trust anchors: 10.in-addr.arpa 16.172.in-addr.arpa 17.172.in-addr.arpa 18.172.in-addr.arpa 19.172.in-addr.arpa 20.172.in-addr.arpa 21.172.in-addr.arpa 22.172.in-addr.arpa 23.172.in-addr.arpa 24.172.in-addr.arpa 25.172.in-addr.arpa 26.172.in-addr.arpa 27.172.in-addr.arpa 28.172.in-addr.arpa 29.172.in-addr.arpa 30.172.in-addr.arpa 31.172.in-addr.arpa 168.192.in-addr.arpa d.f.ip6.arpa corp home internal intranet lan local private test
Feb 03 02:31:17 MyComputer systemd-resolved[327]: Using system hostname 'ArkOS-Folatt'.
Feb 03 02:31:17 MyComputer systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
```

`lsusb`

```
...
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Systemctl is showing `systemd-networkd` and `systemd-resolve` up and running.
Networkctl says that my wired connection status is degraded / configuring.

My `ip a`

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:09:05:c7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::c110:1100:8995:68f2/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe09:5c7/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

My debug log from `journalctl -b -u systemd-networkd`

```
-- Logs begin at Fri 2017-01-13 20:03:08 CET, end at Sat 2017-04-22 13:36:47 CEST. --
Feb 03 02:30:47 MyComputer systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
Feb 03 02:30:47 MyComputer systemd-networkd[298]: Enumeration completed
Feb 03 02:30:47 MyComputer systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Feb 03 02:30:47 MyComputer systemd-networkd[298]: eth0: IPv6 enabled for interface: Success
Feb 03 02:30:49 MyComputer systemd-networkd[298]: eth0: Gained carrier
Feb 03 02:30:50 MyComputer systemd-networkd[298]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 03 03:20:07 MyComputer systemd[1]: Stopping Network Service...
Feb 03 03:20:07 MyComputer systemd[1]: Stopped Network Service.
Feb 03 03:20:07 MyComputer systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
Feb 03 03:20:07 MyComputer systemd-networkd[515]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 03 03:20:07 MyComputer systemd-networkd[515]: Enumeration completed
Feb 03 03:20:07 MyComputer systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Feb 03 05:03:56 MyComputer systemd[1]: Stopping Network Service...
Feb 03 05:03:56 MyComputer systemd[1]: Stopped Network Service.
Feb 03 05:03:56 MyComputer systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
Feb 03 05:03:56 MyComputer systemd-networkd[603]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 03 05:03:56 MyComputer systemd-networkd[603]: Enumeration completed
Feb 03 05:03:56 MyComputer systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Feb 03 05:04:13 MyComputer systemd[1]: Stopping Network Service...
Feb 03 05:04:13 MyComputer systemd[1]: Stopped Network Service.
Feb 03 05:04:13 MyComputer systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
Feb 03 05:04:13 MyComputer systemd-networkd[613]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 03 05:04:13 MyComputer systemd-networkd[613]: Enumeration completed
Feb 03 05:04:13 MyComputer systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Feb 03 06:43:38 MyComputer systemd[1]: Stopping Network Service...
Feb 03 06:43:38 MyComputer systemd[1]: Stopped Network Service.
Feb 03 06:43:38 MyComputer systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
Feb 03 06:43:39 MyComputer systemd-networkd[729]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 03 06:43:39 MyComputer systemd-networkd[729]: Enumeration completed
Feb 03 06:43:39 MyComputer systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd[1]: Stopping Network Service...
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd[1]: Stopped Network Service.
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus object=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=Hello cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.11 object=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=1 reply_cookie=1 error=n/a
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus object=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=AddMatch cookie=2 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.11 object=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=3 reply_cookie=2 error=n/a
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus object=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=RequestName cookie=3 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.11 object=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=5 reply_cookie=3 error=n/a
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: Failed to open configuration file '/etc/systemd/networkd.conf': No such file or directory
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: timestamp of '/etc/systemd/network' changed
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: timestamp of '/usr/lib/systemd/network' changed
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: wlan0: Flags change: +MULTICAST +BROADCAST
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: wlan0: Link 3 added
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: wlan0: udev initialized link
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: wlan0: Saved original MTU: 1500
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: eth0: Flags change: +UP +LOWER_UP +RUNNING +MULTICAST +BROADCAST
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=4 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: eth0: Link 2 added
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: eth0: udev initialized link
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: eth0: Saved original MTU: 1500
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: lo: Flags change: +LOOPBACK +UP +LOWER_UP +RUNNING
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_31 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=5 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: lo: Link 1 added
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: lo: udev initialized link
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: lo: Saved original MTU: 0
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: eth0: Adding address: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe09:5c7/64 (valid forever)
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=6 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: eth0: Adding address: fe80::c110:1100:8995:68f2/64 (valid forever)
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: lo: Adding address: ::1/128 (valid forever)
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: lo: Adding address: 127.0.0.1/8 (valid forever)
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: Enumeration completed
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=7 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: wlan0: Link state is up-to-date
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: No virtualization found in DMI
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: No virtualization found in CPUID
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: Virtualization XEN not found, /proc/xen/capabilities does not exist
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: No virtualization found in /proc/device-tree/*
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: No virtualization found in /proc/cpuinfo.
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: This platform does not support /proc/sysinfo
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: Found VM virtualization none
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: wlan0: Unmanaged
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_33 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=8 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: eth0: Link state is up-to-date
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: eth0: found matching network '/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network'
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: LLDP: Started LLDP client
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: eth0: Started LLDP.
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: eth0: Acquiring DHCPv4 lease
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCP CLIENT (0x26937bab): STARTED on ifindex 2
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Started in Information request mode
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: eth0: Acquiring DHCPv6 lease
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: eth0: Discovering IPv6 routers
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: NDISC: Started IPv6 Router Solicitation client
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=9 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=10 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_32 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=11 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: NDISC: Sent Router Solicitation
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCP CLIENT (0x26937bab): DISCOVER
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Sent INFORMATION-REQUEST
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Next retransmission in 1s
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: lo: Link state is up-to-date
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: lo: Unmanaged
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a object=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_31 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=12 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: Got message type=signal sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.11 object=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=NameAcquired cookie=2 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Feb 03 06:44:09 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: Got message type=signal sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.11 object=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=NameAcquired cookie=4 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Feb 03 06:44:10 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Sent INFORMATION-REQUEST
Feb 03 06:44:10 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Next retransmission in 2s
Feb 03 06:44:12 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCP CLIENT (0x26937bab): DISCOVER
Feb 03 06:44:12 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Sent INFORMATION-REQUEST
Feb 03 06:44:12 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Next retransmission in 3s
Feb 03 06:44:13 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCP CLIENT (0x26937bab): DISCOVER
Feb 03 06:44:13 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: NDISC: Sent Router Solicitation
Feb 03 06:44:16 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Sent INFORMATION-REQUEST
Feb 03 06:44:16 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Next retransmission in 7s
Feb 03 06:44:16 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCP CLIENT (0x26937bab): DISCOVER
Feb 03 06:44:17 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: NDISC: Sent Router Solicitation
Feb 03 06:44:22 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: NDISC: Invoking callback for 't'.
Feb 03 06:44:24 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Sent INFORMATION-REQUEST
Feb 03 06:44:24 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Next retransmission in 16s
Feb 03 06:44:25 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCP CLIENT (0x26937bab): DISCOVER
Feb 03 06:44:40 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Sent INFORMATION-REQUEST
Feb 03 06:44:40 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Next retransmission in 31s
Feb 03 06:44:41 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCP CLIENT (0x26937bab): DISCOVER
Feb 03 06:45:11 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Sent INFORMATION-REQUEST
Feb 03 06:45:11 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Next retransmission in 1min
Feb 03 06:45:14 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCP CLIENT (0x26937bab): DISCOVER
Feb 03 06:46:11 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Sent INFORMATION-REQUEST
Feb 03 06:46:11 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Next retransmission in 1min 49s
Feb 03 06:46:17 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCP CLIENT (0x26937bab): DISCOVER
Feb 03 06:47:21 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCP CLIENT (0x26937bab): DISCOVER
Feb 03 06:48:01 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Sent INFORMATION-REQUEST
Feb 03 06:48:01 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Next retransmission in 2min 3s
Feb 03 06:48:25 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCP CLIENT (0x26937bab): DISCOVER
Feb 03 06:49:30 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCP CLIENT (0x26937bab): DISCOVER
Feb 03 06:50:04 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Sent INFORMATION-REQUEST
Feb 03 06:50:04 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Next retransmission in 1min 55s
Feb 03 06:50:34 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCP CLIENT (0x26937bab): DISCOVER
Feb 03 06:51:39 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCP CLIENT (0x26937bab): DISCOVER
Feb 03 06:52:00 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Sent INFORMATION-REQUEST
Feb 03 06:52:00 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Next retransmission in 2min 10s
Feb 03 06:52:43 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCP CLIENT (0x26937bab): DISCOVER
Feb 03 06:53:48 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCP CLIENT (0x26937bab): DISCOVER
Feb 03 06:54:10 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Sent INFORMATION-REQUEST
Feb 03 06:54:10 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCPv6 CLIENT: Next retransmission in 1min 52s
Feb 03 06:54:53 MyComputer systemd-networkd[746]: DHCP CLIENT (0x26937bab): DISCOVER
```

Answer (score -1):

It's very unfortunate, but I need a

- fully open-sourced,
- Linux-capable,
- System-on-a-Chip,

to migrate to Parabola and not have any network problems, which I don't have.

And such a board does not even exist yet and only [one project](http://www.lowrisc.org/) so far is actually doing something about this.